# java compilation: classname Vs classname with file-extension

Tags: java

Running basic java programs from commands line is a 3 steps process:

1. Write code:

   public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
       System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
   }
2. Compile by `javac HellWorld.java` which would check for errors & generate `HelloWorld.class` file.
3. run code by giving the class name --> `java HelloWorld`

Now,
I am curious to know why:

`java HelloWorld` works but when we give fullpath of the classfile, it throws an error

```
$ java HelloWorld.class 
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld.class
```

What does it make a difference if we give just the classname Vs classname **with** file-extension?

Comment: java looks for the class HelloWorld. when you give HelloWorld.class it looks for the class 'HelloWorld.class"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does it make a difference if we give just the classname Vs classname with file-extension?

The argument you give to the `java` binary isn't meant to be a filename. It's meant to be a class name. So in particular, if you're trying to start a class called `Baz` in package `foo.bar` you would run:

```
java foo.bar.Baz
```

So similarly, if you try to run `java HelloWorld.class` it's as if you're trying to run a class called `class` in a package `HelloWorld`, which is incorrect.

Basically, you shouldn't view the argument as a filename - you should view it as a fully-qualified class name. Heck there may not even be a simple `Baz.class` file on the file system - it may be hidden away within a jar file.

Answer (score 2):

> What does it make a difference if we give just the classname Vs classname with file-extension?

It is because that is the way it is.  Sun / Oracle have implemented the `java` command to work that way since Java 1.0, and changing it would be massively disruptive.

As Jon says, the argument to the command is a fully qualified class name, not a filename.  In fact, it is quite possible that a file with the name `HelloWorld.class` does not exist.  It could be a member of a JAR file ... or in some circumstances, just about anything.

---

In Java 11 and later it is also possible to compile and run a single Java source file *with a single command* as follows:

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

(This possible because Oracle no longer supports Java distributions without a Java bytecode compiler.)

Comment: that was helpful, Thanks for taking time to answer :)

Answer (score -1):

In the Java programming language, source files (.java files) are compiled into (virtual) machine-readable class files which have a .class extension.

When you run java class file after compile then run the following command:

java HelloWorld

Note: Need to setup java classpath

Comment: He knows that. You haven't answered the actual question.